# Entity Framework reference turns null?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I'm filling my reference to the entity model with data, but then it turns into null and I don't understand why.

```
public SummaryContent_Main GetContent(int ID1, int ID2, eComponentType ComponentType)
{
    IEnumerable<vw_WebSiteSummaryContent> entity = null;
    Entities context = new Entities ();

    int maxID = context.vw_WebSiteSummaryContent.Max(webSiteSummaryContent => webSiteSummaryContent.ID);

    entity = context.vw_WebSiteSummaryContent
        .Where(c => c.ID > ID2 && c.CourseID == ID1 && 
               (c.UserID == userToken.UserID || c.Shared == true));

    if (entity.Count() > 0) <<< --- FAILS 
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Exception:

> 'entity.Count()' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'   int {System.NullReferenceException}

When looking at "entity" in Watch, it is not null.
What can cause this problem?

Comment: what does Watch tell you that entity is comprised of?

Comment: The problem come from the query that define the entity. Since the entity is an IEnumerable, the query get executed only when the Count is call. Check if the userTonken is null.

Comment: @Stephan Is there another way of executing it?
I'm checking if the token is null before that (I didn't post the full method), and i got to know if my entity has rows

Comment: Change the declaration from IEnumerable to IList. Add the .ToList() at the end of the query and it will be executed immediately

Comment: @Stephan Now I get the same exception but on that query, before .Count()

Comment: @DaniDev Could you be more specific please? I'm not sure that this is what you meant but it got CommandText,Context etc..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Something *in* the lambda statement is throwing the NRE. You only observe it when you execute `.Count()` because that is when the lambda is evaluated and executed against the data store. Validate your parameters that you are using in the lambda including any nested values.

Comment: @Igor when running the query in SQL Server Management, it works

Comment: Post your Exception Stack Trace. Until you do that we are all just guessing at where in the Lambda the NRE is manifesting.

Comment: Is `userToken` null? I'd put my money on that being null & throwing the `NullReferenceException` when Count() executes which is when the lambda actually runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by a view table - it had more than 1 primary key